Nexus Release artefact - Include config file updated in build stage for Maven Java project
There is a config file which is parameterized in SCM and it fetches the values from secret vault and updates the config file in the build stage, performed in Jenkins.
The updated config file should be part of the release artefact, how to achieve this?
We are able to have the updated config file with secrets in the snapshot artefact. However, the release artefact has the scm version of the config file, with adding checkmodificationexclude configuration in the pom.xml for maven release plugin. But on mvn release:perform it creates the jar with the scm config file, wherein we need the updated config file from local repository.
How to achieve this? We would not intend to push the updated config file to SCM, but need it in the release artefact.
